# Accept Number Special Character and Comma in Input field using Charcode

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I am using charcode so that user can input only number, special-character and comma.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control numOnly" 
onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57">
```

Right now it is accepting only number but I want to allow special character and comma using charcode.

what am I missing?

Comment: What if the client uses copy/paste... I could bet this will cause problems with using `onkeypress`

Answer (score 2):

Try Below

```
<input type="text" class="form-control numOnly" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 32 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

Comment: Thanks, Sirisha,
What if I don't want & and -

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control numOnly" onkeypress="return Validate(event);">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9-!@#$%*?,]");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }       
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can view all the javascript charcodes.

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

The comma one for example is 188.

You can also use https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum to facilitate your life.

Edit: I noticed you have a class named NumOnly there. Is it only for styling?